# Is this normal that api-verify.recaptcha.net points to google.com?

Tags: google

A user just emailed me saying he could not complete registration in my website. I just checked and already found out it's the recaptcha that is causing the problem.

I have been using this recaptcha php library and it has been working perfectly for more than 3 years until today:
https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/php?hl=zh-TW

The recaptcha displays successfully when the registration page loads, but it says `Could not open socket` when it tries to contact the `api-verify.recaptcha.net` during captcha verification.

I suspect there's something wrong with `api-verify.recaptcha.net`, when I ping it, it redirects to `www.l.google.com`.

Is this normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is normal.  [ReCaptcha is a Google product](http://www.google.com/recaptcha), and one of the names of the server that serves it, is indeed, `www.l.google.com`... and here's a screenshot `nslookup` from my machine (below) for you to look at.

[image: nslookup/ping results]

Comment: Now I know what is the real problem, `api-verify.recaptcha.net` has no problem at all. It's my web hosting who silently disabled the `fsockopen` php function (which is used to contact the verification server) for security reasons. I just called them to enable it to temporarily solve my problem.